# JavaScript - iframe inside document: getElemById()

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, document

I have the following page code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="AAA"> SOME CODE </div>
    <div>
      <iframe>
        <html>
          <div id="AAA"> SOME CODE </div>
          <div id="myDiv"> MORE CODE </div>
        </html>
      </iframe>
      <iframe>
        <html>
          <div id="AAA"> SOME CODE </div>
          <div id="myDiv2"> MORE CODE </div>
        </html>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, the fun part.
I can put my hands on the `div "myDiv"`. Then I want to modify the content of div `"AAA"`, the one that is in the same iframe.
However if I do

```
 myDiv.ownerDocument.getElementById("AAA")
```

I get the element outside the iframe - notice there are three elements with id="AAA"...

My question is, given an element, how can I put my hands on its containing iframe, and not on the most top level document?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is using the same ID somehow necessary?

Comment: The document is invalid, the contents of an iframe element can't include an `<html>` element or duplicate ids elsewhere in the document (although the document referenced by the `src` attribute can). Given garbage, browsers will attempt to do a lot of error correction, but often don't do so consistently. Start by writing valid markup, then worry about achieving whatever effect you want.

Comment: Friends, this is the content of Yahoo! Classic email interface. If you have an account there, you're more than welcome to look at their source code. So, given this document with some elementID, and also some iframe with element with the same ID, how can I know in which document\iframe am I?

Comment: Also ID's can't start with numbers! (Weird but true requirement, some browsers accept it, other browsers go whack).

Comment: @Roy T. You're right, I'll update the code. The question still remains - how can I know in which part of the code am I?

Comment: Have you tried `myDiv.parent.getElementById("AAA")`?

Comment: I would be interested to see how you would get the 'myDiv' element as i can't really see why your example code can come back with the wrong div. Also i assume you are actually using the `src` attribute on the `iframe` and then let the content be returned by a new request?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - I tried and it returns the AAA element outside the frame

Comment: @Jan-Peter Vos - as I replied earlier, this is actually Yahoo! Classic email structure. Whenever you open a message it opens in a new tab inside Yahoo interface, which is interpreted as a new iframe. And so if you open two messages you have two iframes, with different src's but their content are the same. The tag without an iframe is the one from the reading pane. I can fetch 'myDiv' for an example if I monitor the email content... But then let's assume i wish to change some common attribute - like AAA div, I can't fetch the correct iframe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of my sleeve, try such function:

```
function GetTopElement(child) {
    var parent = child.parentNode;
    while (parent) {
        var node = parent.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        if (node == "body" || node == "html")
            break;
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    }
    return parent;
}

//usage:
var topLevel = GetTopElement(myDiv);
topLevel.getElementById("AAA")...
```

Comment: Thanks @Shadow Wizard, I marked your answer as the right solution with the slightest modification of if (node == '#document') break; If anyone else has a more elegant solution I'd appreciate it...

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery: `$('iframe').contents().find('#123')`

Comment: Thanks Peter it's a good answer but they don't use jquery in my company's extension. Also please notice the described structure might have multiple iframes and so this answer wouldn't do it.

Comment: if there are multiple iframes, at least you shoud know which one you want. You can get the nth one easily with the help of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the following?

```
first_iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
first_iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('123')
```

Then you can reference sucesive iframes:

```
first_iframes_child = first_iframe.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
...
```

Though I'd advise to your company to use jQuery/Prototype and not use iframes, it'll probably make your life easier.

Comment: I can't use this because I don't know in which iframe I need to take care. Please assume there is more than one iframe. all the iframes have an element with id="AAA".

Comment: The only thing I do know, is the element "myDiv". It is unique (because I plant it there). All I want is to get it's containing iframe...

Comment: Nili - Using multiple IDs on the same page is bad practice. An ID is supposed to be a unique identifier for the given page so that you don't run into this problem. If you need to have a number of DOM elements classified together, you should be using classes.